# Travel Info Related Icons

Tags: icons, android, travel

I have developed an Android App and have chosen the icons as shown below. I am not quite sure if everyone can understand these icons and their relevance. Is there any way I can make them more relevant?

1. Distance
2. Weather
3. Category of the Place
4. Things and Activities to do.

[image]

**Changes made based on slawrence12's suggestions**

[image]

**Need icons feedback for the following**
[image]

The icons in the Action Bar as follows

1. Search
2. Category
3. Sort - this opens a drop downmenu which will have the options

Comment: hey @harsha-m-v could you just say what the app is for? For example if it is a cycling routes app, then I think the distance icon is good, but if not, I would probably change it slightly. Thanks

Comment: Its a Weekend Getaway app. Where it will give you a list of places around a City and the basic information. This is the Place Details View

Comment: @harasha-m-v it would be good to mark this as answered, if you think it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Comments on Original Design**

My thoughts are the following:

- Distance: For distance, maybe you want a more neutral image. Your icon currently suggests that the person will be cycling to the location. So something like this might be better: http://www.solidview.com/content/images/tips/distance-icon.jpg
- Weather: People commonly associate weather with a sun/cloud icon. See second row, second icon here: http://static5.depositphotos.com/1020135/395/v/950/depositphotos_3955508-01-Weather-Forecast-Icons.jpg Having said this if you are just conveying temperature, maybe your current icon is appropriate.
- Categories: If a location can have multiple categories then it is like a tag right? Maybe something like this is suited: http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/download/moth-green/tag-512.jpg
- Activities: I think this needs to suggest an activity, so the icon you used for distance (the person cycling) would be better here.

Just to note, I really like the style of your icons. The images I have linked you to aren't nice looking icons in themselves, but they convey a better concept/form to go inside your own pretty circular designs.

I also think that categories should be moved below the activities section, as I think it has a lower priority.

Hope this is helpful for you.

**Comments on 1st Ammendment**

I wonder if you should also add labels for each section? In a lighter colour, and a smaller font above the content to the right of the icon.

For example I think distance needs a context of where it is calculating from. I guess it uses the 3g/wifi to estimate the user's location, and then creates the distance? So your label above the content could say 'Distance calculated from Oxford, UK'. Because there may be times when the location of the user is slightly out and it's good for a user to know the variable of this calculation.

**Comments on 'Action Bar' icons**

Categories: I think you should carry the categories icon through from the 'Place Information' page, maybe it would be good to reflect this along the vertical axis so that it is is in the same direction as the Search icon.....Though I do like your icon on the menu bar, maybe you should use this one on the 'place information' page.

Comment: have changed and added the screenshot :D thanks :D

Comment: Good Point. Right now the distance will be calculated and fixed from a particular City. This will be for my City Bangalore to get started. Once i am able to understand how i can build the dynamic API for Locations and Places then i think that would make sense. Also i forgot to upload another screenshot for icon recommendation. I need Icons for Category and Sort. i will update the screenshot in my Question

Comment: amended action bar text further

Comment: the options are - sort list by distance, alpha

Comment: then I prefer your current icon to what I suggested :)

Comment: I am back with another Question :D would love ur feedback on this http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/31830/travel-category-icons